# VirtualBox Network <-> Virtual Machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a server (192.168.6.99) and approx. 50 computers. I installed VirtualBox on the same server and created a new machine with Windows Server 2019.

I created a NAT network card (to get access to the Internet and communication Virtual Machine -> Internal network). I added a second network card as Bridged network/adapter which assigns me an IP address for the Virtual Machine 192.168.56.104. The result is that Virtual Machine -> Computers from the local network (Gets a ping connection - that is, may contact, the internet is working). Computers from the local network -> Virtual Machine (connection not possible)

What am I doing wrong? Why can the computers on the computer network not connect to the Virtual Machine?

Comment: You will want to make the VM part of the same subnet to accomplish your goal.  Otherwise it will require modifications tot he rest of your network.

Comment: Either configure the VM with [bridged networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#network_bridged) as @Ramhound suggested or if you need to expose only some ports of the VM (eg if you run a web server) use [port forwarding](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#natforward). See [Table 6.1. Overview of Networking Modes in 6.2. Introduction to Networking Modes](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#networkingmodes)